# convert table to text and match color of separator

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large table where each cell has a single word that is colored. I want to convert this table to text so I can then perform other functions on it.

The problem is that the separators Word puts in are a default color, so my resulting text will be (blue text)(black separator)(green text)(black separator)(yellow text) and so on.

Is there a way to find/replace each separator with a separator of the same color as the preceeding or following word?

Here is what I have currently:

```
Sub PrepareTable()

With Selection
.WholeStory
.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
.Tables.Item(1).Columns(1).Delete
.Tables(1).Range.Select
.Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
    NestedTables:=True
End With

End Sub
```